# Parse.com Push notifications and ordered broadcast

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, chat

I'm implementing Parse push notification. I have 2 receivers. First one will always show notification and second one will take over notification if one particular activity is running. One registered in manifest (priority 1) and the other is registered/unregistered dynamically (priority 2). My problem is that I cant cancel the broadcast from my dynamic receiver by calling

```
abortBroadcast()
```

it throws an exception

```
BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
```

So, is there a way to make the broadcast ordered or something like that?
I really want to handle the data in my activity when it is active.

Comment: are you sure you are using `sendOrderedBroadcast` instead of `sendBroadcast` when sending the `Intent`?

Comment: i'm not using anything. i think the broadcast is send by Parse's own service `PushService` (registered in manifest). I think its not an ordered broadcast. Is there any way to override it? I want my activity to get the data if it is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after 2 hrs of searching, finally solved it. This is what I did,

First I created a base `BroadcastReceiver` which receives the push notification from  Parse. It then removes all actions from received intent and adds a custom action eg, `com.myclass.PUSH`
Then I used

```
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
```

to send a new ordered broadcast using my custom action.

Now I set other two receiver's (the one defined in manifest and my dynamic receiver defined in activity) action to `com.myclass.PUSH`

Now the broadcast is ordered and i can cancel it using `abortBroadcast()`